# Sharepoint 2010 and PDFs

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, pdf

I am a site owner for my job and we use our SharePoint site as a learning management system (LMS).  Our document libraries contain interactive PDFs that students check out, work in, and save back into the library.  The problem is that sometimes (and this is very random), the PDF, when checked out, will not open in acrobat reader like I need it to, but will open in I.E..  This causes the student to loose the ability to save their work and check it back into the library for later reference.  I know when this problem is going to happen because the "red belt" around the page icon next to the document name is missing when this problem occurs.

I can not figure out how to keep this from happening.  There seems to be no real fix for it either.  I need my PDFs (that contain interactive form fields) to be checked out, open in acrobat reader, worked in, saved, and checked back in and I need it every time for every student.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what is your Web Applications General Setting for Browser File Handling...Strict or Permissive? try with strict.http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8073.sharepoint-browser-file-handling-deep-dive.aspx

Comment: Are there perhaps multiple servers in your SharePoint farm and when it doesn't work it is hitting a particular (misconfigured) WFE?

Comment: @Muhimbi - Wow!  I never thought of that. I'll ask my librarian.  Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: Well, it was a server farm issue after all.  We had one server that wasn't configured properly.  After fixing that, all is well.  thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could post this as answer, so future Readers will find the helpful instruction more easily.